# MySQL Problem with foreign key on n:m relation

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I have this database

```
create table ticket
(
  id int auto_increment primary key,
  name varchar(100)
);

create table document
(
  id int auto_increment primary key,
  name varchar(100)
);

create table ticket_document
(
  ticket_id int,
  document_id int
);

insert into ticket (id, name) VALUES (1, "a"),(2,"b");
insert into document (id, name) VALUES (1, "x"),(2,"y");
insert into ticket_document (ticket_id, document_id) VALUES (1,1),(1,2),(2,2);
```

So every ticket can have multiple documents and each document can be referenced to multiple tickets.

I want to achieve, that if I delete a ticket all references to his documents are deleted AND if there is no more reference to one of the document from an other ticket the document is also deleted.
But I don't know how to set the foreign keys.

Comment: You can delete ticket_document when deleting ticket using a on delete cascade FK in ticket_document. You cannot use FKs to fulfil  the requirement to delete document when the last reference to it in ticket_document is deleted. For this periodically sweep documents deleting where no children exist - an event may be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create foreign keys:

```sql
ALTER TABLE ticket_document
ADD FOREIGN KEY (ticket_id) REFERENCES ticket (id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
ADD FOREIGN KEY (document_id) REFERENCES document (id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

After ticket(s) deletion delete rows from `document` explicitly (or use service event procedure):

```sql
DELETE 
FROM document 
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT NULL 
                   FROM ticket_document
                   WHERE ticket_document.document_id = document.id );
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=3636329d5770e871ee7a808432d894d0)

---

Alternatively you may use AFTER DELETE trigger for auto-clearing `document` table:

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER tr_ad_ticket
AFTER DELETE
ON ticket
FOR EACH ROW
DELETE 
FROM document 
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT NULL 
                   FROM ticket_document
                   WHERE ticket_document.document_id = document.id );
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=8c3607615b89c2707a9a596aa4f195f9)

Comment: Ok, so I am not to stupid but there is really no way to automate this completely only with foreign keys?

Comment: @ClausBönnhoff Autoclearing added. I do not recommend, but you may...